# Disconnected warnings while connecting Kafka client to IAM based MSK

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, aws-msk, confluent-cloud

I have configured Kafka client on ec2 instance and I am using aws s3 camel connector to read files from S3 bucket and push it to topic in MSK cluster, For unauthenticated MSK cluster this setup works fine on broker's PLAINTEXT://9092 port.

Using connect-standalone.sh script for this -

> ./bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/CamelAwss3SourceConnector.properties

Now I have enabled IAM authentication on MSK cluster and disabled PLAINTEXT, In order to connect my kafka client I made below changes to my config/connect-standalone.properties  file -

- Downloaded aws-msk-iam-auth-1.1.6-all.jar and copied under Kafka/libs/ folder on ec2 instance having my kafka client.
- created named profile with "abc" on my ec2 instance
- updated below configs in connect-standalone.properties

1. security.protocol=SASL_SSL
2. sasl.mechanism=AWS_MSK_IAM
3. sasl.jaas.config = software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required awsProfileName="abc";
4. sasl.client.callback.handler.class=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler

after above changes when I try connecting to broker's on MSK on 9098 port with same script -

> ./bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/CamelAwss3SourceConnector.properties

I keep on getting below warnings and errors in logs and no data is pushed to my topic in MSK -

Errors in logs -

WARN [Producer clientId=connector-producer-CamelAws-s3SourceConnector-0] Bootstrap broker b-1:9098 (id: -3 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:1036)
WARN [Producer clientId=connector-producer-CamelAws-s3SourceConnector-0] Bootstrap broker b-3:9098 (id: -2 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:1036)
WARN [Producer clientId=connector-producer-CamelAws-s3SourceConnector-0] Bootstrap broker b-2:9098 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:1036)

ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=CamelAws-s3SourceConnector-0} Failed to flush, timed out while waiting for producer to flush outstanding 1 messages (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:512)
ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=CamelAws-s3SourceConnector-0} Failed to commit offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceTaskOffsetCommitter:116)

I also tried -

> bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list b-2,b-3:9098,b-1:9098
> --topic newtopic --producer.config config/connect-standalone.properties

Above is able to send messages to MSK cluster on 9098 port,
It seems like CamelAwss3SourceConnector.properties is using PLAINTEXT , I tried to add  -

> camel.component.kafka.security.protocol=SSL

but it fails with below error -

> Error configuring property: camel.component.kafka.security.protocol
> because cannot find component with name kafka

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you configured the [policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/iam-access-control.html#create-iam-access-control-policies) also?

Comment: updated issue, so it is able to send messages with this profile on 9098 port with kafka-console-producer.sh script but I want to use CamelAwss3SourceConnector as producer and facing challenges while configuring SSL for that.